# AngularJS pagination disable link when data loading

Tags: angularjs

I'm using AngularJS pagination to create links to pages.

```
  <pagination total-items="totalItems" max-size="'10'"
              ng-model="currentPage" ng-change="pageChanged()"></pagination>
```

How do I disable links when the data are loaded?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

1. Use a boolean `$scope` variable let's say, `$scope.fetching = false`.
2. Add `ng-disabled` to your `<pagination>` directive.

   ```
   <pagination total-items="totalItems" max-size="'10'"
         ng-model="currentPage" ng-change="pageChanged()
         ng-disabled="fetching"></pagination>
   ```
3. In your `pageChanged` function, at the top of the function set `$scope.fetching = true` and at the end of your `pageChanged` function set `$scope.fetching = false`